# scaleTime minimum tick value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale

Using d3 I have an xAxis defined as

```
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([fromDate, toDate])
  .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

function customXAxis(g) {
  g.call(xAxis);
  g.select(".domain").remove();
  g.selectAll(".tick line").attr("stroke", "white");
  g.selectAll(".tick text").attr("fill", "white");
}

g.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(customXAxis);
```

All is working very well indeed.

However, I would like the scale to show ticks at a minimum of a day.  As it stands if fromData and toDate are only a few days difference it show ticks....

```
Mon-10___12PM___Tue-11___12PM___Wed-13___12PM___Thu-14___12PM
```

How can I get it to not show the time of day values?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just a suggestion: change your question's title to *minimum tick interval*, not value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [intervals](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/master/README.md#intervals) in the axis generator:

> Constructs a new custom interval given the specified floor and offset functions and an optional count function.

For instance, this is your code as it is (the domain here has just 3 days):

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([new Date("January 1, 2017 00:00:00"), new Date("January 4, 2017 00:00:00")])
  .range([20, 480]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,100)")
  .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```

Now the same code, with `d3.timeDay`:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([new Date("January 1, 2017 00:00:00"), new Date("January 4, 2017 00:00:00")])
  .range([20, 480]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .ticks(d3.timeDay)
  .tickFormat(d=>d3.timeFormat("%a %d")(d));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,100)")
  .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```

PS: the `tickFormat` is just to change the first tick, don't pay attention to it.